# About dynamic assignment of attributes in Python 2.x

Tags: python

When I try to dynamically add attributes to instances of object class, I get an AttributeError. However, it is possible do it with instances of subclasses of object.
Does anybody know why?

```
>>> obj = object()
>>> obj.new_attr = "some value"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'new_attr'
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> obj.new_attr = "some value"
>>> print obj.new_attr
some value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a note in the documentation about that:

http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object

> **Note**: `object` does not have a `__dict__`, so you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the `object` class.

There is also a discussion about this on python mailing list:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-October/614249.html

Comment: How can `object` not have a `__dict__`, but all of its subclasses have one implicitly? That kind of breaks inheritance.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) in object-oriented programming doesn't require base classes must have the same attributes as its subclasses — only that  subclasses inherit the features of their superclass.

Comment: @martineau Fair. I can't think of a CS principle that applies here, so I'll borrow one from evolutionary biology: it is very annoying that the presence of the `__dict__` attribute is a polyphyletic trait.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: Well, as a computer scientist, I naturally tend to think in logical, not biological, terms. `;¬)` Although a subclass instance should be able to be used just like an instance of its baseclass could be, due to the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), the reverse is not necessarily true. Actually in Python it's possible for a subclass to also not have a `__dict__` if it declares [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__slots__).